# Scala Mockito: Discarded non-unit value for Unit declaration

Tags: scala

Can someone please explain what this means

> `Error:(32, 28) discarded non-Unit value
>       dataFrameReader.load() wasCalled once`

I've looked at some online articles and I don't quite understand it.

This is my code snippet from a ScalaTest with Scala Mockito

```
 ...
 val dataFrameReader = mock[DataFrameReader]
 dataFrameReader.format(anyString) shouldReturn dataFrameReader
 dataFrameReader.option(anyString, anyString) shouldReturn dataFrameReader
 dataFrameReader.load() wasCalled once
```

If I take out the `wasCalled once` then it works fine

I don't understand what this means though as I am invoking "wasCalled" on what load() returns and `wasCalled once` resolves to a unit

What am I missing here?

Comment: You return a value of/last value is of a type different from `Unit`, whereas the expected return type is `Unit`, so the value is discarded (can be a symptom of bad design)

Comment: I don't follow, can you explain a little more please

Comment: @cchantep It seems to return `Unit`: https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala/blob/e0e6ee5d78025569ebd8c1f8936515a1eb3aae07/core/src/main/scala/org/mockito/IdiomaticMockito.scala#L45.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are mocking [`DataFrameReader.load`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fe317dc74e5fa1509ae9d735485f66724f7292e5/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala#L169) from Apache Spark, then its return type is actually `DataFrame` and not `Unit`:

```
def load(): DataFrame
```

On the other hand, return type of [`wasCalled`](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala/blob/09cc5a6ad56302241790d5da6b0e3836e5d80788/core/src/main/scala/org/mockito/IdiomaticMockito.scala#L45) is indeed `Unit`:

```
def wasCalled(t: Times)(implicit order: VerifyOrder): Unit
```

Thus we have a situation similar to

```
def f(): Unit = {
  g() // g returns DataFrame which gets discarded by f
}

def g(): DataFrame
```

which gets flagged by compiler if `scalacOptions += "-Ywarn-value-discard"` is set.

The issue has been [resolved](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala/pull/88) since [mockito-scala 1.2.2](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-scala_2.12/1.2.2/jar).

Comment: OK so how do I resolve this for the above example? I've tried different things, extract variables and functions etc but can't get past this. Is it a flaw in the Mockito library?

Comment: Consider disabling the compiler flag just for tests like so: `scalacOptions in Test -= "-Ywarn-value-discard"`

Comment: how about programmatically?

Comment: Instead of `wasCalled` we could `import org.mockito.Mockito._` and use the equivalent but old vanilla syntax `verify` like so: `verify(dataFrameReader, times(1)).load()`

Comment: That's actually what I have been doing! Is it a flaw in the Mockito Scala library?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala/pull/88) is a pull request that might resolve the issue.

Comment: Updating to mockito-scala 1.2.2 should resolve the issue.

Comment: hmm. Doesn't for me (running 1.17.7). I wonder if it's because the function I'm mocking returns `F[Unit]`